# CSS3 rotation in Chrome for Linux

Tags: html, css

I was trying out some CSS3 features such as rotation...
I looked at some tutorial and I put together the following simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.example {
    color: red;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Chrome & Safari */
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678, sizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE 7-8 */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<dic class="example">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That works in Firefox but not in Chrome for Linux.
I couldn't test it in any other OS/browser. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no `<dic>` HTML element - should be `<div>`